# Will I pay tax in my account in India if I get a transfer from UK from a different party

Tags: taxes, india, international-transfer, gift-tax

I stay in India and have a salary savings account here. A friend of mine is making a transfer from UK in GBP to my account in India. Amount is 35000 pounds.

Do I face any taxes, legal liability or charges for this transfer?

Comment: Oh yes. That amount is huge and will surely flagged up. First by the bank, who will want to know the source of the income.

Answer (score 1):

> Taxes

Yes. You haven't indicated why the transfer is being made. If it is without any reason, it would attract a Gift Tax.

> legal liability

It would definitely be investigated to see if Money Laundering or any other illegal activities is happening. If things are in order you have nothing to worry.

> charges

Normally none. Your Bank can confirm better.

> friend of mine

Are you sure he is a friend and this is not some kind of scam ... it typically starts of with you will get huge money and then calls like its stuck with RBI you need to paysome one to fast track or any such stories to get money out of you.

Comment: +1 for the "friend of mine" comment. OP xyz needs to learn the abc's first!